# No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I want to run this code from cmd with the following line:

```
python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=5000
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
2024-01-19 21:35:58.289319: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\models\ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 35, in <module>
    from official.legacy.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official.legacy'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\RealTimeObjectDetection\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 30, in <module>
    from object_detection import inputs
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\inputs.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 70, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor as ssd_efficientnet_bifpn
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\models\ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 37, in <module>
    from official.vision.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\efficientnet\efficientnet_model.py", line 37, in <module>
    from official.vision.image_classification import preprocessing
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\preprocessing.py", line 25, in <module>
    from official.vision.image_classification import augment
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\augment.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing import image_preprocessing as image_ops
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing'
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\RealTimeObjectDetection\RealTimeObjectDetection>
```

python version 3.11.5
tensorflow version 2.15

I want to develop an object detection program. The mentioned line in cmd is used for training the model.

Comment: Kindly check the version of Tensorflow what your using make sure it should be compatible with the version of the object detection API. And check all required modules installed in your environment. If there are missing 
Modules like ‘official.legacy’ or ‘tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing’, please install by using pip.